# Get object properties value in javascript received via json from Controller as Hashtable

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I read here some topics how to get properties values from an object.

In my case, I have something in Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetSomething() {

return Json( new {
     data = AModel.Get()
     }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet );

}
```

In model:

```
public static List<Hashtable> Get() {
    List<Hashtable> list = new List<Hashtable>( 0 );
    Hashtable table = new Hashtable();
    table.Add( "ITEM_1", "Value1" );
    table.Add( "ITEM_2", "Value 32" );
    list.Add( table );

    table = new Hashtable();
    table.Add( "ITEM_1", "Value22" );
    table.Add( "ITEM_2", "Other" );
    list.Add( table );

   return list;
}
```

And in Javascript:

```
var test;
 $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "Action/Controller",
    data: {},
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
            test = data.data;
         },
    complete: function () {
            console.log(test);              
 });
```

I got in console like in the following image:

[image]

I want to get the value of property `ITEM_1` and results to me : Value1, Value22.

I tried with

```
for(var key in test) {
console.log(test[key].ITEM_1);
//console.log(test[key].ITEM1);
}
```

but it not works.

Of course, I renamed `ITEM_1` key into `ITEM1` (in model) but same result : `undefined` but in console I see the values for all object.

[image]

Help me please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`test` is an array and not an object. loop through the array like:

```
var testLength = test.length;            //caching length, performance benefit
    i, item1;

for(i=0;i<testLength;i++){
    item1 = test[i].Properties.ITEM1;
}
```

Comment: Doh, what's simple :) I forgot to loop test with `for` statement :)

Comment: @MichaelSwan `for in` is only used in objects and not arrays.